# Which syllable is stressed in 'meeker'?

Tags: syllables

Which syllable is stressed in 'meeker'? I have looked in the dictionary, and just found the transcription of 'meek'.

Comment: The *meek* shall inherit the stress.

Comment: @deadrat So the stress is on the first syllable?

Comment: Yes, rhymes with beaker.

Comment: Yes, that is the case with most comparatives, except where the comparative element is being deliberately stressed e.g. I didn't say he was *meek*, I said he was *meekER*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pronounced /ˈmiːkə(ɹ)/, to rhyme with "beaker" and "leaker" -- the accent is on the first syllable.

Comment: He was meeker because the spot on his pants revealed that his beaker was a leaker.